# PHP calculation

Tags: php, html, math

I'm trying to output a value from xml this is what I do -

```
<?php
    echo $responseTemp->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating;
?>
```

This outputs 4.5, but when I change it to the code below it displays as 8. Why isn't it displaying as 9? Thanks.

```
<?php
echo $responseTemp->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating*2;
?>
```

Comment: could you try `echo (float)$responseTemp->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating * 2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try casting the value to a numerical value first.

```
$num = (double) $responseTemp->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating;

echo $num * 2;
```

See [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [String Conversion to Numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) on the PHP website for more information.

Comment: Yeah, if you are expecting a double, enforce that it will be.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a decimal value without doing typecasting, you have to multiply by a number with a decimal. Otherwise it will return a regular integer like the number you gave it.

Try multiplying by 2.0

```
echo $responseTemp->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating*2.0;
```

Comment: Enforcing the expectation on the known number seems less useful than making sure that the variable is what you expect it to be, e.g. `echo (double) $responseTemp->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating*2.0;`

Comment: I know it's not proper, I was just offering another explanation as to why it wasn't working.